# UItextField data disappears when I scroll through the TableView -- Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having problems with my app. I have a table view where every cell consists of a textfield. When i write in it and scroll down, than scroll back up, the data i wrote in it disappears.

These are some of my functions in ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
    var rowBeingEdited : Int? = nil

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return initialNumberOfRows
    }

    var count: Int = 0;
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell



        if(arrayOfNames.count > 0 && count < arrayOfNames.count) {
            cell.TextField.text = self.arrayOfNames[indexPath.row]
        }else{
            cell.TextField.text = ""
        }

    count += 1



        cell.TextField.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.TextField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let row = textField.tag
    if row >= arrayOfNames.count {
        for _ in ((arrayOfNames.count)..<row+1) {
            arrayOfNames.append("") // this adds blank rows in case the user skips rows
        }
    }

    arrayOfNames[row] = textField.text!
    rowBeingEdited = nil

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    rowBeingEdited = textField.tag
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm saving all of my written text in the textfield into an array. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you scroll back up `tableView(tableView: cellForRowAt:)` gets called again. Inside that method you increment count every time that is called, thus instead of using the first condition it goes to the second conditional statement that sets `cell.TextField.text = ""` as count is probably greater than `arrayOfNames.count`. What are you using `count` for? Maybe rethink how you could code that part a little better.

Comment: count gets incremented because I'll get an out of bounce error for trying to access an element in my array

Comment: Instead maybe do `indexPath.row < arrayOfNames.count` so you won't access an element outside of your array.

Answer (score 1):

You cells are recreated. So you lose them. You could use the method `PrepareForReuse` to set the text back when they are recreated.

Comment: Can you guide me a little more on how to do that?..I can't find that method